# How to fix error which appeared after upgrading to react-router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Before upgrading to v6 I had this part of code, which worked as it should:

```
//before
return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route render={(props) => (
                <div className={`layout ${themeReducer.mode}`}>
                    <Sidebar {...props}/>
                    <div className="layout__content">
                        <TopNav/>
                        <div className="layout__content-main">
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path='/' exact component={Dashboard} />
                                <Route path='/activity' component={Activity} />
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
```

After upgrading I only changed `Switch` to `Routes` and `component` to `element` and expected it to work, but it didn't.

```
Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.
```

Tried many things, but nothing helped. How can I make it work the way it worked before the upgrading?

```
//after
return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route render={(props) => (
                <div className={`layout ${themeReducer.mode}`}>
                    <Sidebar {...props}/>
                    <div className="layout__content">
                        <TopNav/>
                        <div className="layout__content-main">
                            <Routes>
                                <Route path='/' element={<Dashboard/>} />
                                <Route path='/activity' element={<Activity/>} />
                            </Routes>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
```

Comment: The `Route` that is a direct child of `BrowserRouter` should be wrapped in `Routes`.

Comment: I'm just interested why before upgrading to v6 `Route` was outside `Switch`, but still worked

Comment: In RRDv6 `Route` components required only a routing context *somewhere* above it in the ReactTree. The `Switch` component was only used really to switch from inclusive routing, i.e. render all matching paths, to exclusive routing, i.e. render only the first matching path. The `Routes` component replaces the `Switch`, and also pulls double duty handling the route matching. In RRDv6 all routes/paths are now always exactly matched, but you can render as many matches as you need. There just can't be anything between the `Routes` and `Route` components other than these layout/wrapper components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the `Route` rendered by `BrowserRouter` needs to be wrapped in a `Routes` component and also render JSX on the `element` prop or wrap a child React component.

It appears to be a layout component so abstract it out into its own component that renders an `Outlet` for the nested `Route` components. If `Sidebar` isn't a function component to use the React hooks then use the hooks in the layout component and pass them as props to `Sidebar` as before. Note that if `Sidebar` previously used the `history` object that it was replaced by a `navigate` function in RRDv6.

```
import { Outlet, useLocation, useMatch, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const match = useMatch();
  // ... etc....

  return (
    <div className={`layout ${themeReducer.mode}`}>
      <Sidebar 
        location={location}
        match={match}
        navigate={navigate}
        ...... etc....
      />
      <div className="layout__content">
        <TopNav/>
        <div className="layout__content-main">
          <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

...

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />} >
        <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/activity" element={<Activity />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```